# Filtering out empty API responses to avoid errors

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise

Basically I've made a program where words are inputted and their definitions are found using Wordnik API. Each word is then displayed dynamically and the definition is shown on click. Here's that code:

```
function define(arr) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var client = [];
    var definitions = {};
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            client[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
            client[i].onreadystatechange = function() { 
                if (client[i].readyState === 4 && client[i].status === 200) {
                    if (client[i].responseText.length === 0) {
                        console.log(client[i].responseText);
                        client.responseText[0] = {
                            word: arr[i],
                            text: 'Definition not found'
                        };
                    } 
                    definitions[arr[i]] = JSON.parse(client[i].responseText);
                    if (Object.keys(definitions).length === arr.length) {
                        resolve(definitions); 
                    } 
                }
            };
            client[i].open('GET', 'http://api.wordnik.com:80/v4/word.json/' + arr[i] +
                '/definitions?limit=1&includeRelated=false&sourceDictionaries=all&useCanonical=false&includeTags=false&api_key=',
                true);
            client[i].send();
        })(i);
    }
});
}

function makeFlashCards() {
    var data = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
    var wordsToDefine = ignore(makeArr(findUniq(data)));
    define(wordsToDefine).then(function(result) {
        success(result);
    }).catch(function(reason) {
        console.log('this shouldnt run');
    });
}

function success(obj) {
    document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = '';
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            addElement('div', obj[prop][0].word);
        } 
    }
    attachDefinition(obj);
}

function addElement(type, word) {
    var newElement = document.createElement(type);
    var content = document.createTextNode(word);
    newElement.appendChild(content);
    var referenceNode = document.getElementById('form');
    document.body.insertBefore(newElement, referenceNode);
    newElement.id = word;
    newElement.className = "flashcards";
}

function attachDefinition(obj) {
    var classArr = document.getElementsByClassName('flashcards');
    for (let i = 0, len = classArr.length; i < len; i++) {
            classArr[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                cardClicked.call(this, obj);
            });
    }
}

function cardClicked(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById(this.id);
    if (obj[this.id].length !== 0) {
    if (this.innerHTML.split(' ').length === 1) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'https://www.wordnik.com/img/wordnik_badge_a2.png';
        el.innerHTML = obj[this.id][0].text 
            + ' ' + obj[this.id][0].attributionText + '<br>';
        el.style['font-weight'] = 'normal';
        el.style['font-size'] = '16px';
        el.style['text-align'] = 'left';
        el.style['overflow'] = 'auto';
        el.appendChild(img);
    } else {
        el.innerHTML = obj[this.id][0].word;
        el.style['font-weight'] = 'bold';
        el.style['font-size'] = '36px';
        el.style['text-align'] = 'center';
        el.style['overflow'] = 'visible';
    }
}
}
```

When the `define` function is given an array with all valid words, the program works as expected however if any word in the array argument is not valid the program doesn't add click event handlers to each element. I think this might have to do with the `catch` being triggered.

When an invalid word is requested Wordnik API sends back an empty array which might be the root of this problem. I tried to account for this by adding

```
if (client[i].responseText.length === 0) {
    console.log(client[i].responseText);
    client.responseText[0] = {
        word: arr[i],
        text: 'Definition not found'
    };
```

but this conditional never ends up running.

I need some way of filtering out the empty array responses so the `catch` is not triggered and the program can run smoothly.

Comment: You should delete your API key from your sample code, if it is valid

Answer (score 0):

When you get to `if (client[i].responseText.length === 0)` make sure that `client[i].responseText` is returning empty string. It is probably `undefined` in which case `client[i].responseText.length` will throw an error and this will cause the `catch` block to execute.

```js
function makePromise() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var test = undefined;
    if (test.length === 0) {
      resolve("resolved");
    }
  });
}

makePromise().then(console.log).catch(function(res) {
  console.log('Error was thrown')
});
```

Try changing that condition to:

`if (client[i].responseText && client[i].responseText.length === 0)`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that still isn't getting the conditional to fire.

Comment: Actually it did fire I just had to parse the JSON string.